# Hadoop - Execute script when data arrives in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, execute

Is there a tool in the Hadoop ecosystem which can actually know if new data has been added to the HDFS File System ?

Actually I want to execute remotely a sqoop import job from an external database (no merge, only new table). Then when this data is written in HDFS, it would execute a spark script that would process with the newly data added and do some stuffs.

Is there any feature in Hadoop that does this kind of job ?

I could totally execute the spark script after the sqoop import job is done, but I would like to know if such feature exists and haven't find any yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. there is. There's a workflow tool called Oozie within Hadoop ecosystem to handle this kind of scenario.

Oozie provides workflow which can be triggered to run either based on a fixed schedule or data availability. In your case, it'll be considered as data availability. see more details at Oozie doc here : [Oozie doc for coordinator job](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a1._Coordinator_Overview)